# Unable to AddClass to html form jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to add class (**daterange daterange-inline**) to form element **date_range** when user clicks the **Add a Row** button, I do not know what I may be doing wrong. The class is added to date field when page loads but does not work when user clicks **add a row** button, it just displays normal text box. I have also tried inserting the class directly in the form without Jquery method, but still fails.

Html

```
<div id="student_entry">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="control-label"
                       style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo get_phrase('week'); ?></label>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="15" class="form-control"
                       name="week[]" value="<?php echo $row1['week']; ?>" data-validate="required"
                       data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required'); ?>"
                       required/>
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- DATE RANGE PICKER -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"
                       style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo get_phrase('date'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" required name="date[]"
                       class="form-control date_range"
                       data-format="MMMM D, YYYY"
                       value="<?php echo $row1['date']; ?>">

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"
                       style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo get_phrase('activities'); ?></label>
                <textarea class="form-control autogrow" required name="activities[]"
                          id="field-ta"
                          placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('activities'); ?>"><?php echo $row1['activity']; ?></textarea>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="student_entry_append"></div>
<!-- add a row when User click button -->

    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                    onclick="append_student_entry()">
                <i class="entypo-plus"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('add_a_row'); ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var blank_student_entry ='';
$(document).ready(function() {
    blank_student_entry = $('#student_entry').html();
    $(".date_range").addClass("daterange daterange-inline");    
});

function append_student_entry()
{
    $("#student_entry_append").append(blank_student_entry);
}

 function deleteParentElement(n) {
        n.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(n.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check something is overwriting your css class. If needed apply !important rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add class you need to trigger the date picker on the element so your function should look like this :

```
function append_student_entry()
{
    $("#student_entry_append").append
(blank_student_entry);
$('input.date_range' ).daterangepicker();
}
```

This will trigger the date picker on input elements with class of `date_range`

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just amend your append_student_entry function to do this:

```
function append_student_entry()
{
    $("#student_entry_append").append(blank_student_entry);
    $(".date_range").addClass("daterange daterange-inline");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did that but it added the class to the whole form. I want it ti be applied only on the date element

Comment: Is the date element a child element of #student_entry_append?
@4jean, try my above edited code.

Comment: I have tried the edit but does not work. Only the background of the textbox change

Comment: The date element is a child of student_entry not append_student_entry, or is it possible to insert class inside. html()

Comment: Can you create quick fiddle of something as I'd like to understand the issue a bit better. Thanks.